# Working of grep in xv6 implementation?

Tags: grep, c, xv6

```c
char buf[1024];

void
grep(char *pattern, int fd)
{
  int n, m;
  char *p, *q;

  m = 0;
  while((n = read(fd, buf+m, sizeof(buf)-m-1)) > 0){
    m += n;
    buf[m] = '\0';
    p = buf;
    while((q = strchr(p, '\n')) != 0){
      *q = 0;
      if(match(pattern, p)){
        *q = '\n';
        write(1, p, q+1 - p);
      }
      p = q+1;
    }
    if(p == buf)
      m = 0;
    if(m > 0){
      m -= p - buf;
      memmove(buf, p, m);
    }
  }
}
```

I found a implementation of `grep()` in `xv6` source code. I think there is a problem in the source code.
Consider the situation like there is a file containing a line more than 1024 character long and it contains the string `unix` (for example) after `1023th` byte {abccee....unix...} and we are searching for that the string.

Now if we run the `grep` it will read the first `1023` character and as it doesn't find any newline character `'\n'` it discards the buffer by setting `m = 0` then next time when it reads the rest of the line it finds the string `unix` and prints only from 1023th` byte {..unix...} but logically it should print the whole line but it simply discards the previous
portion of the line. So, I don't think it works correctly.

Note: I am considering the line starts with 0th, 1st, 2nd byte so on ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lines longer than 1024 bytes aren’t processed correctly. V6 `grep` had [a similar limitation](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/grep):

> Lines are limited to 256 characters; longer lines are truncated